# Regex to split the email address in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this:

```
email = 'serebro@gmail.com'
```

I want a regex to get this:

```
output = ['serebro', 'gmail', 'com']
```

I.e given an email address I want a list which contains the name, company_name and its domain type as the output

I can do something  like this:

```
regex_1 = re.compile("(?:@|^)[^@]*")
regex_1.findall("serebro@gmail.com")
```

which gives me:

```
['serebro', '@google.com']
```

How do i do get `['serebro', 'gmail', 'com']` in python

Comment: I think `(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)` should be enough if you pass email addresses to the regex.

Comment: What is expected result if you have more than one dot in email ,e.g `xen.m.rph@gmail.co.uk` ?

Comment: What about emails like `foo@bar.co.uk`? Do you want these to be returned as `['co', 'uk']` or `['co.uk']`? What about eails like `foo@bar.surrey.sch.uk`? Do you want these to be returned as `['surrey', 'sch', 'uk']` or `['surrey.sch.uk']`? What about emails like `foo@tld`? Do do you need to worry about hitting this edge case?

Comment: 1. the fist part of the email, that is the name could contain alphabets\numbers and '.' a dot as well, in that case, what could i do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest

```
import re
email = 'serebro@gmail.com'
print(re.findall(r'(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)', email))
# => [('serebro', 'gmail', 'com')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FS5LXw).

Or maybe a `re.search` will be better ([demo](https://ideone.com/4S3NLI)):

```
import re
email = 'serebro@gmail.com'
m = re.search(r'(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)', email)
if m:
    print(list(m.groups()))
# => ['serebro', 'gmail', 'com']
```

The `(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more chars up to the last `@` (that should be followed with any 0+ chars and a dot, as the dot is an *obligatory* subpattern), then captures into Group 2 any chars as many as possible up to the last `.` and then matches and captures into Group 3 all the rest.

**Pattern details**:

- `(.+)` - Capturing group 1: matches any 1 or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible (greedily), up to the *last* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns:
- `@` - a `@` (that must be followed with 1 or more chars and an obligatory `.` after)
- `(.+)` - Group 2 matching any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the
- `\.` -  last `.` in the string that is followed by
- `(.+)`   - Group 3 matching any 1+ chars other than line break chars up to the string end.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hm5uAM/1).

Comment: This may not behave as expected for `person@company.co.uk`.

Comment: @CoryKlein: Well spotted, perhaps, in that case, a separate regex could be run first with all the possibilities like `.co` listed in it, like [`(.+)@(.+)\.((?:co|more)\.[^.]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/C1m09d/2). And only if it does not find matches, the simpler `(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)` can be used. Or just use [`^(.+)@(.+?)\.((?:(?:co|more)\.)?[^.]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/C1m09d/4/).

Comment: If I find a list of such TLDs, I will be able to update the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, not exactly, when you say _until the last `@`_ you should say _until the last `@` followed by a `.`_, as the regexp on `a.b@c.d@e` will produce `["a.b", "c", "d@e"]`.  In this special case it was _until the previous to last `@`_.  See https://regex101.com/r/qboGrn/1/ for a demo.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Yes, backtracking will go on until all the subsequent *obligatory* subpatterns are matched. I add detailed explanations of my regexps to 99.9% of answers, and once the answer goes to 0.1%, people start posting these comments :(

Comment: @LuisColorado: I will add an explanation after a medical appointment.

Comment: Well, I will not continue this thread, as it is clear that you feel bad about my comment.  Sorry for the inconvenience and my apologies.  Good luck at the doctor.  By the way, there's no backtracking on this regexp mapping.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Backtracking is always in place when greedy quantifiers are used. There is no backtracking when *possessive* quantifiers are used. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hm5uAM/1/debugger), it shows backtracking steps with the red arrows on the right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use re.split()

```
import re
email = 'serebro@gmail.com'
output = re.split(r'[@.]', email)
```

Comment: If you have hello.world@gmail.com, this fails.

Comment: the fist part of the email, that is the name could contain  alphabets\numbers and  '.' a dot as well, in that case what could i do

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
import re
email = your.email@gmail.com
regex = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+)\.([a-z]+)', email)

regex.group(1) --> 'your.email'

regex.group(2) --> 'gmail'

regex.group(3) --> 'com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that valid email addresses may be much more complex.
Interesting article about it: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Examples (from this article):

```
Abc\@def@example.com
Fred\ Bloggs@example.com
Joe.\\Blow@example.com
"Abc@def"@example.com
"Fred Bloggs"@example.com
customer/department=shipping@example.com
$A12345@example.com
!def!xyz%abc@example.com
_somename@example.com
```

Comment: wow, that is indeed complex, but I don't think I might encounter it in what I'm trying to do, thanks for the great article.

Answer (score 0):

For those who needn't regex,

```
email = 'serebro@gmail.com'
first_part, second_part = email.rsplit('@', 1)  # the real @ will be the last one
domain_name, tld = second_part.split('.', 1) 
print(first_part, domain_name, tld)
# => serebro gmail com
```